# Grails migrate data from sqlite to mysql

Tags: hibernate, grails, database-migration

I am using grails 3.3.2 and want to migrate the data from sqlite to mysql.

Since grails can export schema DDL for both database.

Are there any easy ways to transfer the data?

Thanks.

Comment: The gist of it: Dump your SQLLite to SQL, try to load it into MySQL, fix errors, try again

Comment: I don't think it a easy way.

Comment: Would you like to migrate your app datasource from SQLLite to MySql or you need to migrate some other databases using grails app?

Comment: The app has generated some data in SQLLite, and want to import these data into MySql. Grails can handle the DDL for me.  But the data migration seems not easy.